# How do you display a character with ncurses in Rust?

Tags: rust, ncurses

I'm trying to just add a character into the terminal by simply doing

```rust
use ncurses::*;
fn main()
{
    initscr();
    addch('#');
    endwin();
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:11
   |
15 |     addch('#');
   |           ^^^ expected `u32`, found `char`
```

I checked [the documentation](https://docs.rs/ncurses/5.99.0/ncurses/fn.addch.html) and it says that it takes a `chtype`, so I figuered that was just a character? I'm not sure how I am supposed to change a character to a `u32`. What is the difference between a `char`, and a `chtype`?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code `chtype` [defined as an alias to `u64`(for 64bit platforms) and `u32`(for 32 bit platforms)](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/1e89a6212278d8219557bafa6734c9c40ce03912/src/ll.rs#L19-L23).

```
#[cfg(feature="wide_chtype")]
pub type chtype = u64;
#[cfg(not(feature="wide_chtype"))]
pub type chtype = u32;
```

In order to to solve the error, you can [type cast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.as.html) `#` to `chtype`.

```
fn main()
{
    initscr();
    addch('#' as chtype);
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's quite a strange designe choice isn't it? When would a character ever be a `u32`?

Comment: @Kalcifer It might be due to the fact that `addch` have to interface with [C implementation of `addch`](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/1e89a6212278d8219557bafa6734c9c40ce03912/src/ll.rs#L47)

Comment: Note that in addition to the need to interface with the C library, [Rust `char` _is_ a 32-bit unsigned integer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.char.html#representation).

Answer (score 0):

`chtype` holds more than a character, as described in the ncurses [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html):

```
      ncurses
           the "normal" library,  which  handles  8-bit  characters.   The
           normal   (8-bit)   library   stores  characters  combined  with
           attributes in chtype data.

           Attributes alone (no corresponding character) may be stored  in
           chtype or the equivalent attr_t data.  In either case, the data
           is stored in something like an integer.
```

For more information, the [`waddch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) manual page elaborates:

```
   Video attributes can be combined with a character  argument  passed  to
   addch  or  related  functions by logical-ORing them into the character.
   (Thus, text, including attributes, can be  copied  from  one  place  to
   another  using  inch(3x)  and  addch.)   See the curs_attr(3x) page for
   values of predefined video attribute constants  that  can  be  usefully
   OR'ed into characters.
```